# Dragging Windows Between Workspaces Freezes UI

Tags: unity, compiz, workspaces

I am having a problem on two systems when I enable multiple workspaces and try to move windows between them (zoomed out using the workspaces button on the unity bar) the UI freezes.

To replicate: 
Enable Workspaces
Click on the Workspaces button on the left
Take a window and drag it to another workspace

Once it crosses the threshold to another workspace the workspace screen doesn't return to Unity. If you hit a key (like ALT) the window snaps to wherever the mouse is but the workspaces screen is unable to return to the Unity interface. The only way I was able to get back was the kill -HUP

Both system's are using AMD GPUs and I tried the open and closed drivers.

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this?